# Setup Route 53 to latest docker AWS/ECS stack hostname

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-route53

I'm new to AWS and having a hard time navigating what seems like a basic task. I have a docker-generated AWS configuration for a django app, and want to point my domain to this app.

Specifically I'm using docker compose and have successfully launched a demo app (Django+PostgreSQL if relevant) that's accessible through the docker-generated hostname (`<semi-random>.<region>.elb.amazonaws.com`), and properly displays to the Django site. However I've noticed that each time I `down`/`up` the docker instance, the load balancer hostname seems to be a new randomly generated name (specifically `<semi-random>` part above). I also have a domain name & nameservers registered in Route 53, but the domain doesn't point anywhere yet.

How can I configure my domain to point to the latest version of my docker-generated web service?

Comment: "hostname seems to change randomly" - which hostname? Your load balancer hostname? If you have the LB, it shoudn't matter what is your instance IP or dns name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried to clarify a bit.
 `docker compose up` seems to generate a load balancer that properly routes to my django app, but if I run `docker compose down` then `up` again, it seems to tear down the loadbalancer as well and create a new one (with a new name) when I recreate it. I'm not sure if I'm just not supposed to ever tear down the docker generated services (so the load balancer hostname never changes), or if I'm supposed to be setting up some separate load balancers to point to the "latest" docker-generated balancer, etc.